# Есть ли какие либо библиотеки/способы, чтобы программа, которую я хочу написать могла зайти на сервер в майнкрафт?

Tags: java, c++, бот, rust, minecraft

Я хочу написать бота для майнкрафта. Мне нужна какая то библиотека или гайд для того, чтобы моя программа могла задать себе ник (как в TLauncher), зайти на сервер майнкрафта (по айпи) и управлять персонажем на нем. Очень желательно чтобы все это было без открытия окна майнкрафта, мне нужен только персонаж.

Язык программирования не критичен, но приветствуются Rust, C++ и Java.

Буду благодарен даже если просто укажете направление в котором мне искать такое

Comment: а можно указать программе, куда ей тыкать чтобы открыть майнкрафт?

Comment: Нет, такой способ не подходит

Comment: То что вы хотите это по сути клиент для игры, просто клиент с отсутствующей графикой и более самостоятельный (с функцией бота). А так поищите спецификации по которым работает сервер и по ним писать или второй вариант реверс инженеринг. В любом случае все это долго и тяжко. С открытым окном то проблем меньше но перехват данных от клиента.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Все правильно, как сказал @Kers в комментариях. Есть также более продвинутые боты, когда происходит верификация клиента и нужно использовать именно игровой клиент, а не самописный. Тут 2 варианта:

Читать память клиента и на основе этого делать ввод (это если бот простой нужен, например боты помощники вроде триггер-ботов, которые быстро выполняют действия при выполнении какого-то условия).

Если нужен серьезный самостоятельный бот, тогда нужно копать в сторону OpenCV (либа, которая поможет парить растр игрового клиента боту и видеть его как 3д пространство с элементами, а не как 2d картинку). И после на основе этого симулировать ввод с клавиатуры/мышки/чего угодно еще. Но это, конечно, довольно серьезная работа и обычно такие боты коммерциализируются и их делает не 1 человек.

Также хочу порекомендовать поиск фреймворков для написания ботов по майнкрафту. Сам с Minecraft знаком не супер сильно, но это популярная игра, поэтому наверняка будут готовые бот фреймворки, которые будут иметь базовый набор функций для упрощения передвижения, взаимодействия с миром и т.п., что может сделать написание бота более выполнимой задачей.

Comment: Спасибо за ваш ответ

Answer (score 0):

Наверное уже похдно отвечат, но отвечю. Есть прога Minecraft console CLient с исходным кодом. Для чат бота топ. Можно даже там ходить и не будет открываться окно.